# Use of "as" when describing circumstances

Tags: grammar

In a sentence with four parts,

1. As sharing crime statistics for
2. the year 2011, the Commissioner admitted that
3. there had been an undue delay in
4. the setting up of an anti-narcotics cell.

I am told there is an error in part 1: *as* should not be used. But I don't understand why that's so.

What is wrong with *as,* and what should go there instead?

Answer (score 2):

‘As’ can often replace 'while' (considering temporal usages only):

> As the car sped along the highway, the young boy watched the desert
>   for coyotes.
>
> While the car sped along the highway, the young boy watched the desert
>   for coyotes.

(The second version carries at least a hint that when the car turned off the highway, he stopped watching.)

However, the two words do not have exactly the same distribution:

> While sitting in the car, the boy saw a mule deer.
>
> While he was sitting in the car, the boy saw a mule deer.
>
> As he was sitting in the car, the boy saw a mule deer.
>
> *As sitting in the car, the boy saw a mule deer.

The sentence needs 'As he was sharing ...' or 'During the process of sharing ...' . 'While sharing ...' would be acceptable, but has a faint hint of informality to my mind, so I wouldn't choose it here.